# Pressing movement keys to a program without focus? C#

Tags: c#, winapi, postmessage, sendinput

Possible simulating in C# a long press of (Down\Right\Left\Up) keys to a program without focus in C#?

-SendInput does simulate those keys but require focus.

-PostMessge\SendMessage does simulate keys without focus but not movement keys and not long clicks.

Any more suggestions in C#?

Is there a language that its actually possible?

Comment: [UI Automation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/ui-automation/ui-automation-overview).

Comment: Have you checked UI Automation to see if it helps?